# Get current thumbnail for file, thumbnail indicator. Using .NET

Tags: .net, thumbnails, dropbox, indicator

Using .NET:

1. When we create file windows create thumbnail for it, how to get it?
   I do not need generate new, I need get current thumbnail.
2. When we add image to dropbox folder(or svn folder) it shows some indicator for each thumbnail:

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/27690133/CTD_2012_1_28_19_50_18_121.jpg

Is this indicator just part of thumbnail or it is separate image above thumbnail?

I need to know what indicator has thumbnail.